# TreeView prepends a GUID before ID in rendered HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, treeview

Working in a .NET MVC project with aspx views. I have a partial view with this tree view:

```
<%    
 TreeNode treeNode = Model.TreeNode;   
 treeNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
 tv1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
 tv1.ExpandAll();
%>

<form runat="server" id="form1">
 <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="tv1"  ShowLines="true" EnableClientScript="true">
 </asp:TreeView>
</form>
```

But renders a div with an id prepended with a guid screwing up JavaScript code for expand/collapse (which means it doesn't work). Why?

```
<div id="46ea7e79-e351-46fa-93cc-597e7cfe280b_tv1">
 <table style="border-width:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody><tr>
   <td><a id="46ea7e79-e351-46fa-93cc-597e7cfe280b_tv1n0" href="...">..</a></td>
   <td><span id="46ea7e79-e351-46fa-93cc-597e7cfe280b_tv1t0">...</span></td>
  </tr></tbody>
  ...
 </table>
</div>
```

I am loading the partial view using Ajax and appending content to a div.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the GUIDs are coming from the MVC Web Forms view engine, where it gives a random ID to the ASP.NET Page that is created. In Web Forms, control IDs are hierarchical, so a control will have its parent control's ID prepended to it (in this case the Page is the ancestor). I don't remember why it does this, but I think it was to work around some bug.

Having said that, using a `<form runat="server">` with an ASP.NET Web Forms `TreeView` control is definitely not supported in MVC. So, even if you fix the GUID issue, it's still not supported to use Web Forms controls in MVC.

Comment: I have been running a gridview control this way in this project and have had no problems. I guess you mean it may work but not guaranteed? Still wonder why the hell they would replace an id with an invalid one!

Comment: @petern Right, some controls work by coincidence, but they are not really supported.

Comment: I finally got the Ids to sanity, (setting this.Id on the partial) but the JavaScript generated still had references to g-u-i-d_data kind of variables. Took @Eilon advice and ditched it. Using jstree now. Thanks.